# How to return sprite from method to main and then draw it?

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

I wrote following code but it doesn't print picture. I just see black screen and nothing else. Texture refuses to appear.

These code is just illustration of problem that I faced. Basically my aim is to create sprite with particular `TextureRect` and send this sprite to main where I can set texture for this sprite and then draw it.

Please advise me if you can what I should do

ps. I tried to set texture to sprite inside of method but then I get white rectangular without texture

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Sprite_draw
{
public:    
   sf::Sprite print()
    {
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(10, 10, 10, 10));
        return sprite;
    }    
};

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    while (app.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (app.pollEvent(event))
        {

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                app.close();
        }

        Sprite_draw sprite1;
        sf::Texture texture;
        texture.loadFromFile("cb.bmp");
        sprite1.print().setTexture(texture);
        app.clear();
        app.draw(sprite1.print());
        app.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Joachim Pileborg thk a lot for answer
Will learn how to pass by reference 
Won't ever find solution without you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems with your `Sprite_draw::print` function: One is that it returns an object *by value*, i.e. it's a copy. The other problem is that it's a copy of a *local* variable. So each time you call the function a *new* object is created for the `sprite` local variable, and a new *copy* of that is returned.

The first problem means that every time you do e.g.

```
sprite1.print().setTexture(texture);
```

you only modify the (temporary) copy returned by the function. The second problem means that it doesn't matter how many times you call the function, it will always create a brand new object for the local variable.

One possible solution is to make the local variable a *member* variable in the class, and return a *reference* to it.